# Getting Rails Table to Show up on homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So here is my dilemma. I have created a rails scaffold named posts for a blog I am working on. What I want to be able to do is to display posts on the homepage. If anyone has any info or can point me towards a tutorial, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes, wherever you have :root pointing to, you can set your posts to @posts in the controller method, then iterate over them in the view. In other words:

Config/routes.rb

```
:root to => "pages#home"
```

This means your "home page" points to the home method in pages controller. So:

app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
def home
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

Then in app/views/pages/home.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
  <%= post.body %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps!